# Composition of measurable functions, continuous on one variable, measurable on another variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f\colon \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(\cdot, t)$ is measurable for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for almost all $x \in \Omega$. Show that the function $F \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x) := f(x, u(x))$ is measurable if $u \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

If the function $f$ is bounded from below and $u_k \to u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ show that
$$ \int_\Omega f(x, u(x)) \, dx \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_\Omega f(x, u_k(x))\, dx.$$

My attempt: I tried using the Carathéodory definition of measurable sets, by setting $\alpha > 0$ and the set $E_\alpha :=\{x \in \Omega \colon F(x) > \alpha\}$, to prove $F$ is measurable given that $u$ is measurable on $\Omega$, it suffices to show that $E_\alpha$ is measurable set, that is
$$\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E_\alpha) + \mu(A \cap E_\alpha^c)$$ for any given $A \subset \Omega$. However, I am stuck at this stage. Is there any way to carry on the process to prove measurablility of $F$ or are there any other alternative methods to solve this question?

For the second part of this question: Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$ be so that $f(x,t)\geq M$ for all $(x,t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ then for each $k$ define
$$f_k\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f_k(x) := f(x, u_k(x)) - M$$ is nonnegative and measurable function on $\Omega$. As $u_k \to u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ then $u_k \to u$ in measure so that $f_k \to F - M$ in measure as well following the continuity assumption. By Fatou's lemma for convergence in measure,
$$\int_\Omega F(x) - M\, dx = \int_\Omega f(x,u(x)) - M\, dx \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}\int_\Omega\left( f(x, u_k(x)) - M \right)\, dx$$ and given that $\Omega$ is bounded then we have $$ \int_\Omega f(x, u(x)) \, dx \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_\Omega f(x, u_k(x))\, dx.$$